# How do I query the Github API using gh CLI for a PRs with specific keyword in title?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to query the Github API using `gh` CLI for all PRs with the word `Bump` in the title however I fail to figure how...

I have tried:

```
api --method GET /repos/my_name/my_project/pulls -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -f q="Bump in:title"
```

and

```
api --method GET '/repos/my_name/my_project/pulls?q=Bump in:title' -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"
```

however the filtering does not apply

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the search api instead:

`gh api '/search/issues?q=is:pr+repo:my_name/my_project+Bump+in:title`